# Clean solution for Rive and Riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod, rive

In my flutter app I want to use Rive for animations and Riverpod for state management. So now I'm looking for a performant way to listen to the state of my provider to manage the state of my `SMIInput<bool>`. Currently I wrap the Rive widget with a consumer, to get the state from riverpod and set the controllers value.

```dart
Consumer(builder: (context, watch, _) {
  _smile?.value = watch(widget._stateRef).smile;
  return Rive(
    artboard: _riveArtboard!,
  );
});
```

I suppose that this runs the build method of the Rive widget once `_smile.value` is set and once it returns the widget.

**- Am i getting this right?**

For that purpos i tried calling addListener to the providers notifier to set `_smile.value` there.

```
context.read(widget._stateRef.notifier).addListener((logoState) {
   if (mounted) {
     _smile?.value = logoState.smile;
   }
});
```

But this runs just one time and not on every state change as I hoped it does.

**- Are there other suggestions for altering the controllers input values without need to use Consumer?**

```
final signInLogoSmileProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<LogoNotifier, LogoState>((ref) {
  // ignore: unused_local_variable
  ref.watch(signInFormProvider);
  final signInFormNotifier = ref.read(signInFormProvider.notifier);
  return LogoNotifier(smile: signInFormNotifier.shouldSmile);
});
```

I need to watch `signInFormProviders` state instead of signInFormProvider.notifiers state for the same reason addListeners only runs one time.

**- Is this bad practice, or am I doing something wrong here?**

If you had any nice implementations of **Rive and Riverpod hand in hand**, I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using a newer version of Riverpod and Rive, but you could do it easily by using a `ConsumerStatefulWidget` and then listening to the value changes with `ref.listen` and then setting the value to `SMIBool`.

```dart
//...
late SMIBool _smile;
//...
_onInit(Artboard artboard) {
 this._artboard = artboard;
 _smile = controller.findInput<bool>('smile') as SMIBool;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ref.listen(signInLogoSmileProvider,
       (previous,  next) {
      // change value
      _smile.value = next;
   });

   return RiveAnimation.asset(
         riveFileName,
         artboard: 'board',
         onInit: _onInit,
       );
   }
}
```